# Bootstrap 4 modal not focused when showing

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 to show modal, I have a problem when click on the button to show it it's not appear as focused on the other page content .
and that's what I am trying:

```
    <div class="add-advertise">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#advertiseModal" class="btn btn-primary">AddAdvertise</button>
            </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="advertiseModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

like this pic:
[image: image of modal]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like the overlay is appearing over the content. Use the DOM inspector to check the `x-index` of the elements and update them

Comment: yes I have a main header with z-index 1002.How can I update the z-index of modal to appear above the header without remove the z-index of he header

Comment: Make its `z-index` higher than the value on the overlay

Comment: I set it 1003 and the same problem still appeared

Comment: @rawanmansour consider moving the modal to be a direct child under your `body` element. [If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Comment: @Matt Thank you set it as answer if you want, you solve my problem.

Comment: Glad it solved it for you. Just added it as an answer for anyone else landing on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider moving the modal to be a direct child under your `body` element.

From [Sara Cope](https://css-tricks.com/author/saracope/) on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/):

> Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.